# inject scope into angular material modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-material

I'm trying to open a modal using angular material and inject the scope of the parent, where my data is.

I am attempting to loosely follow the custom/advanced example here:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog

I do not need the dialog to do anything once closed, so I've eliminated the Dialogcontroller, which seems to only handle 'cancel' and 'answer' upon close. (correct me if I'm wrong here)

**The ultimate goal here is to have access to survey in the modal, which is an object in the scope of the parent.**

My parent HTML has the review button:

```
<input type="button" value="Review" ng-click="vm.openReview($event)" />
```

which triggers the function:

```
(function () {
    appModule
    // parent controller
    .controller('tenant.views.surveys.index', [
        '$scope', 'abp.services.app.survey', '$filter', '$mdDialog',
        function ($scope, surveyService, $filter, $mdDialog) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.openReview = function (ev) {
                $mdDialog.show({
                    //controller: DialogController,// not needed
                    templateUrl: "/App/tenant/views/surveys/review_modal.html",
                    parent: angular.element(document.body),
                    targetEvent: ev,
                    clickOutsideToClose: true,
                    fullscreen: true
                })
                //.then(function (answer) {// not needed
                //    vm.modalStatus = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
                //}, function () {
                //    vm.modalStatus = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
                //});
            };

            // not needed
            //function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
            //    $scope.hide = function() { $mdDialog.hide(); };
            //    $scope.cancel = function() { $mdDialog.cancel(); };
            //    $scope.answer = function(answer) { $mdDialog.hide(answer);  };
            //}
        }
    ])
```

.

```
   // then the modal controller
    .controller('tenant.views.surveys.review', [
        '$scope', 'abp.services.app.survey',
        function ($scope, surveyService) {
            var vmModal = this;
        }
    ]);

})();
```

Now, in my modal, I have some content:

```
<div ng-controller="tenant.views.surveys.review as vmModal" class="md-padding dialogdemoBasicUsage" id="popupContainer" ng-cloak="">

    <div ng-controller="tenant.views.surveys.review" class="md-padding dialogdemoBasicUsage" id="popupContainer" ng-cloak="">

    <md-dialog aria-label="Mango (Fruit)">
        <form ng-cloak>
            {{vmModal.survey}}
        </form>
    </md-dialog>
</div>
```

But I think I'm missing a piece. I don't think vmModal actually contains the scope of the parent. I want access to vmModal.survey.

Do I need to / can I inject the scope directly into the modal controller?

Comment: Try adding `scope: $scope` to the object passed to `show`. Are you actually using `$scope` though? Looks like you are using `controller as`.

Comment: Not sure how to convert between $scope and controller as, when looking at examples & such.

Comment: How about sharing the survey via a service instead?

Comment: Your HTML is still messed up and the part where you are setting `vmModal.survey` is missing. Please provide a full example via codepen etc.

Comment: Since I can't rewrite this thread without messing up all the responses, I've started a new one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551362/injecting-scope-into-angular-material-dialog